# pay from customer to another customer in my app use paypal or stripe?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, stripe-payments

I am developing an application that has a function allow an customer pay to another customer.Can I use Paypal mobile or Stripe? how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has a full solution of this. This is call stripe connect.

Suppose you have a marketplace and you have buyer and seller. Now you want to send money directly to your seller.

For this situation you can use stripe connect.

To use stripe connect your seller need to connect with his/ her stripe account (similar as facebook or social media login).

When you use stripe connect a charge will deduct from buyers account which is called stripe charge. Another type of charge you can deduct from your buyer which is called application fee. You can set your own application fee.

Money will send directly to seller's stripe account after deducting stripe charge and applicatipn fee. You also have full refund option in stripe comnect.

Comment: But does it mean that on registration of the user I need to get and keep the user's paypal account info in order to make the transfer in the future? How do I get the account info?

Answer (score 0):

There're several options for you to implement a person-to-person payment function, but you may want to check with [**venmo**](https://developer.venmo.com/) as the most convenient way for an native APP integration

Answer (score -1):

Stripe is one of the popular gateway for receiving payment in Canada, if you have user base of canada than i would recommend using stripe, you can find the integration kit [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)

Paypal is also good option you can get the documentation of paypal integration [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/).

For Paypal account you need to verify your email id & bank accounts same is for stripe.

Comment: I have read doc of Paypal but I only see use case user buy a product and pay for it.I don't find how to for user pay another user